# Chained promises keep being executed despite rejection in the chain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have the code below and i want to stop the execution when a rejection occurs in order to do a rollback. However even if there are rejects in the chain it keeps executing.

```
__cacheHandheldData(userResult.handhelduuid).then((oldhandheldId) => {
  olduuid = oldhandheldId;
  __cacheUserdata(userResult.userdata_id) //userResult.userdata_id
}).then((x) => {
  __reconciliateToNewUserData(userResult.userdata_id, handheldData.uuid)
}).then((x) => {
  __linkUser(userResult._id, handheldData.userdata_id, handheldData.uuid)
}).then((x) => {
  __unlinkUser(olduuid)
}).then((x) => {
  __attachMergedUserdata(userResult.handhelduuid)
}).then((x) => {
  __cleanHandheld(userResult.handhelduuid)
}).then((x) => {
  __cleanUserdata(userResult.userdata_id)
}).then((x) => {
  __cleanHandheldCache(userResult.handhelduuid)
}).then((x) => {
  __cleanUserdataCache(userResult.userdata_id)
}).then((x) => {
  __removeHandHeldFromRedis(userResult.handhelduuid)
}).then((x) => {
  console.log('reached to destination')
  var response = {};
  response.errorCode = '00';
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.send(201, response);
  return next;
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('[general]', err)
});
```

each of these __functions are of form

```
function __cacheHandheldData(oldhandhelduuid){
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{});}
```

Comment: you missed the return statement on the individual function calls. that way they are not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the promises in the `.then()` handlers as in:

```
}).then((x) => {
    return __reconciliateToNewUserData(userResult.userdata_id,handheldData.uuid)
 // ^^^^^^ add return here to return the promise
}).then((x) => {
```

Only when you return a promise from within a `.then()` handler is it actually added into the chain.  Without that, it's just an independent promise chain that has no connection at all to the parent chain.  `.then()` handlers have no magic powers to know when asynchronous operations executed within them are done.  The only way they can know is if you return a promise that represents the asynchronous operation.

Once it is part of the chain (by returning the promise as shown above), if any of those returned promises reject, then they will abort the whole chain (up to the next `.catch()`).